# initialize Hammer.js for all elements with same id

Tags: jquery, html, hammer.js

i want use hammer js to build a double Tab gesture for like post.
Html :

```
<div class="gitem-wrap row">
      <div class="gitem">
        <div class="well">
            <figure id="img-item"><img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></figure>
            <article>
                ...
            </article>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gitem">
        <div class="well">
            <figure id="img-item"><img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></figure>
            <article>
                ...
            </article>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Js to initialize Hammer js :

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('img-item');
var mc = new Hammer(myElement);
mc.on("doubletap", function() {
    //myElement.toggleClass('liked');
    console.log('Double tap!');
    return false;
  });
```

it's just work for first element but not for all .
How can i initialize Hammer js for all elements with same id?

**JSFIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/

Thanks for helping. its work great in hammer.js v1
http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/3
 but in new version (2.0.4) there is problem and `$('figured').toggleClass('liked')` not work after doubletap. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/4

Comment: *for all elements with **same id*** That is invalid. Use class instead.

Comment: Check the updated code below or in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate IDs are considered as invalid (and not a good practice). IDs should be unique. Use a different method like class/TagName.

[MDN source : **Element.id**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) : *It must be unique in a document*

```
$('figure').each(function(){   //tagname based selector
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    mc.on("doubletap", function() {
        console.log('Double tap!');
        alert('Double tap!');
        //$(myElement).toggleClass('liked');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/1/)**

<sub>Providing a jQuery solution as you have tagged jQuery</sub>

Alternatively, replace duplicated Ids by class, and use a class based selector.

```
<figure class="img-item">
```

---

```
$('.img-item').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var mc = new Hammer(this);
    mc.on("doubletap", function() {
        console.log('Double tap!');
        alert('Double tap!');
        $this.toggleClass('liked');
        return false;
    });
});
```

The fiddle with `$(this).toggleClass('..')` did not work because `this` inside `on()` refers hammer object and not current object.

Comment: its work great in hammer.js v1 http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/3/  but in new version (2.0.4) it not work. http://jsfiddle.net/ekdfokc5/4/